# Creating trading card board layout in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, ui-design

I wanna make a trading card game using libgdx. I have a general idea about how to implement the server side of the game and the game rules, but I don't know how to design the visual interface of the game (in the client side). I want to
create a layout similar to the one in the image below, but quite a bit simpler. I don't have an idea of how to do it though. I'm thinking of using `scene2d` and `Table`  and have a row the opponent, one for the player and two for the creatures and then each cell is a card/creature. Is that a good way or is there a better way?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether to use or not to use scene2d.ui as your interface i would say the answer is a definitive yes. As many people here will tell you that reinventing the wheel is not really the most efficient way to go about things.

The ui framework provided by libgdx is really powerful and should be taken advantage of whenever possible. Combine it with some form of tween framework and you can achieve very flashy effects akin to that of a AAA game like hs.

This feels like more of a design question though.